# Need to exit/enter australia on visit visa

Tags: customs-and-immigration, australia, cruising

I need to exit/enter Australia before a "particular date"... I am on a multi-entry visit visa and must not enter after this "particular date";

Will taking a cruise in the open seas constitute leaving/entering Australia?

For e.g a [sample cruise](https://cruises.flightcentre.com.au/cruise/details/8/409/1768381) which leaves sydney - goes to open seas and returns after 3 days.

any other ideas? hoping for some guidance...

Thanks

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, however your example cruise might not actually enter "open seas" - I suspect iit may just stay in  coastal waters

Comment: Why not a flight to Singapore/Malaysia/Indonesia and back? It would be cheaper and definite.

Comment: Can you explain why you need to do this? A multi-entry visa does not mean you *have* to enter multiple times, it just *allows* you to visit multiple times.

Comment: actually, I can stay for a maximum of 12months from date of each arrival... so if I come back one day before this "particular date"... I can use the same visa for 364 more days :)

Singapore, Malaysia, Indonesia are a little pricey around the holiday period (which is when my particular date falls).... but might have to do this after all :(

Comment: @AIqbalRaj What kind of visa is that? I highly doubt with visit visa, you will be allowed to stay for years.

Comment: A cruise which does not stop in any other country is very unlikely to make you leave Australia. But agree that your attempted visa run is probably a bad idea and likely to raise issues.

Comment: Note that a 0600 visitor visa for instance has a condition of “Cannot stay for more than 12 months in any 18 months period”, as well as “must leave before visa expiry” https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/already-have-a-visa/check-visa-details-and-conditions/see-your-visa-conditions?product=600-29B#

Comment: @AnishSheela Ignoring the visa run issues, flying to NZ is going to be quicker than flying to anywhere in Asia.  EG SYD=>AKL 3 hours, SYD=>Bali 6+ hours.  Also SYD=>Fiji 3+ hours. (Unless of course you are doing this from Darwin)

Comment: Have you asked the cruise company what kind of visa (if any) they require?

Comment: It would probably be easier to answer this if you provide details of the visa: subclass, arrive-by date, attached conditions, etc.